# lldb affecting rcx value upon EXC_SYSCALL

Tags: macos, x86-64, lldb, xnu

I noticed that upon an invalid 64bit MacOS `syscall`

```
    xor eax,eax
    syscall
;lldb stops here after the syscall
```

When lldb stops the process **while single stepping** on:

```
thread #1, stop reason = EXC_SYSCALL (code=5797, subcode=0x1)
```

The `rcx` is equal to `rsp`. However when lldb is not attached or is not single stepping `rcx` is equal to expected return address after the `syscall` (i.e. is exactly of the same value as `rip` in user space). Is this some kind of a bug / side effect?

I'm observing this on MacOS 10.14.5, lldb-1000.11.38.2 also 10.14.6, lldb-1001.0.13.3

After some investigation relevant XNU [code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-4903.221.2/osfmk/x86_64/idt64.s.auto.html) seems to be:

```
Entry(hndl_syscall)
    TIME_TRAP_UENTRY

    movq    %gs:CPU_ACTIVE_THREAD,%rcx  /* get current thread     */
    movl    $-1, TH_IOTIER_OVERRIDE(%rcx)   /* Reset IO tier override to -1 before handling syscall */
    movq    TH_TASK(%rcx),%rbx      /* point to current task  */

    /* Check for active vtimers in the current task */
    TASK_VTIMER_CHECK(%rbx,%rcx)

    /*
     * We can be here either for a mach, unix machdep or diag syscall,
     * as indicated by the syscall class:
     */
    movl    R64_RAX(%r15), %eax     /* syscall number/class */
    movl    %eax, %edx
    andl    $(SYSCALL_CLASS_MASK), %edx /* syscall class */
    cmpl    $(SYSCALL_CLASS_MACH<<SYSCALL_CLASS_SHIFT), %edx
    je  EXT(hndl_mach_scall64)
    cmpl    $(SYSCALL_CLASS_UNIX<<SYSCALL_CLASS_SHIFT), %edx
    je  EXT(hndl_unix_scall64)
    cmpl    $(SYSCALL_CLASS_MDEP<<SYSCALL_CLASS_SHIFT), %edx
    je  EXT(hndl_mdep_scall64)
    cmpl    $(SYSCALL_CLASS_DIAG<<SYSCALL_CLASS_SHIFT), %edx
    je  EXT(hndl_diag_scall64)

    /* Syscall class unknown */
    sti
    CCALL3(i386_exception, $(EXC_SYSCALL), %rax, $1)
    /* no return */
```

I do indeed get the `rax` value as the `(code=xxxx)` reported by `lldb`. And the subcode 1 also matches.

The parts relevant for returning to user space are:

```
EXT(ret64_iret):
        iretq               /* return from interrupt */
L_sysret:
    /*
     * Here to restore rcx/r11/rsp and perform the sysret back to user-space.
     *  rcx user rip
     *  r11 user rflags
     *  rsp user stack pointer
     */
    pop %rcx
    add $8, %rsp
    pop %r11
    pop %rsp
    sysretq             /* return from system call */
```

and also

```
L_fast_exit:
    pop %rdx            /* user return eip */
    pop %rcx            /* pop and toss cs */
    andl    $(~EFL_IF), (%rsp)  /* clear interrupts enable, sti below */
    popf                /* flags - carry denotes failure */
    pop %rcx            /* user return esp */
    sti             /* interrupts enabled after sysexit */
    sysexitl            /* 32-bit sysexit */
```

So I actually did disassemble the MacOS 10.14.6 kernel binary found at `/System/Library/Kernels/kernel`.

<strike>Interestingly the `sysret` variant **is not there** at all. Only the `iret` and `sysexit`.</strike>

Looking at 64bit relevant part *really helps*.

```
                     _ret64_iret:
ffffff800019985a         iretq                                                  ; CODE XREF=_idt64_debug+38, _ks_64bit_return+118, _ret64_iret+25DATA XREF=_idt64_stack_fault+32

                     loc_ffffff800019985c:
ffffff800019985c         cmp        eax, 0x1                                    ; CODE XREF=_ks_64bit_return+170
ffffff800019985f         je         loc_ffffff8000199875

ffffff8000199861         pop        rax
ffffff8000199862         pop        rcx
ffffff8000199863         add        rsp, 0x8
ffffff8000199867         pop        r11
ffffff8000199869         pop        rsp
ffffff800019986a         sysret

                     loc_ffffff800019986d:
ffffff800019986d         pop        rax                                         ; CODE XREF=_ks_64bit_return+179
ffffff800019986e         verw       word [rsp-0x30+arg_50]
ffffff8000199873         jmp        _ret64_iret

                     loc_ffffff8000199875:
ffffff8000199875         pop        rax                                         ; CODE XREF=_ret64_iret+5
ffffff8000199876         pop        rcx
ffffff8000199877         add        rsp, 0x8
ffffff800019987b         pop        r11
ffffff800019987d         verw       word [rsp-0x20+arg_20]
ffffff8000199882         pop        rsp
ffffff8000199883         sysret
```

Comment: The kernel might be using a different syscall return-path in a process being single-stepped.  Linux does this (using `iret` to work around exploitable CPU bugs in `sysret` if a debugger might have set a non-canonical RIP https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e7d0c41ecc2e372a81741a30894f556afec24315/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L133), but IDK about the XNU/Darwin kernel in MacOS.  See also [amd and intel programmer's model compatibility](//stackoverflow.com/q/54379076) where I wrote more detail about CPU bugs with `sysret` in an answer.

Comment: `CCALL3` is the failure case when RAX doesn't match any of the 4 classes it checks for.  The normal path is `je EXT(hndl_mach_scall64)` or `je EXT(hndl_unix_scall64)`

Comment: @PeterCordes yes that's my understanding. I updated my question with "fresh" `XNU` source link and added some remarks. Is the `sysexit` vs `iret` while single stepping a plausible explanation of what I'm observing?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize 64-bit kernels would ever use `sysexitl` to return to 32-bit userspace.  It's interesting that the `sysexit` return path does load user-space ESP into RCX, but I'm pretty sure your code can't be using it. 
 The 64-bit `sysret` return path obviously returns to user-space with RCX=RIP because that's how `sysret` works.   You'll need to look at the `iret` return path to see what it does.