# How to set a breakpoint on an assembly file using Xcode?

Tags: xcode, assembly, lldb

I tried "breakpoint [line number]", "breakpoint filename.s:line_number" but they don't work. Currently I have to step through all lines, and it's a hassle

Comment: I don't know about xcode or lldb but that usually means you did not assemble/link with line number debug info. Look into that. Even so, you should be able to set breakpoints using addresses or any symbols that may still be available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **an alternative** you can:

1. show memory with assembly instructions with

   di
   with explicit arguments

if you need reach out further

```
di -c 1000 ;
```

if you need to disassemble a specific address

```
di -s <address>
```

2. set a memory break point with

   br s -a

**Another alternative** / (not valid for MacOS Monterey 12.x and newer)
is slightly more destructive but actually more effortless , which may or may not be useful in your case. You can make an invalid syscall in your assembly code. Your program will happily continue execution but `lldb` will break on the **next instruction** after the syscall with `SIGSYS`/`EXC_SYSCALL`. You haven't specified if you're targetting x86-64 or arm so the setup will differ slightly.

For **x86-64** you'd have

```
syscall
```

Assuming your `rax` register does not happen to be a valid syscall i.e in `0x2000xxx` range the destructive part will include:

1. Zeroing upper 32bits of `rax` register
2. `r11` will become `rflags`
3. `rcx` will become `rip` (it's used by the XNU kernel for returning to the user space from the `syscall`), *however* if you single step `rcx` will become `rsp` as mentioned by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57523462/lldb-affecting-rcx-value-upon-exc-syscall)

For **32 bit** and **64bit arm**  you can make a system call with:

```
svc 0x80
```

Btw any 1 byte^ number will work, but by convention it's `0x80`.
32bit uses `r12` for syscall number. 64bit uses `x16`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56993314/5329717) & [here](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Kernel_Syscalls). So basically valid ranges are `0x0` - `0x0xxx`. Even invalid syscalls seem to affect `x0` & `x1` (for 64bit, as I don't have a 32bit device to test). So as long as you take into account `x0` & `x1` being affected after the syscall and happen to have `x16` that is an invalid syscall you're good to go.

**UPDATE**
To @PeterCordes excellent remark yet **another alternative** for x86 is:

```
int3
```

i.e. debugger trap

arm equivalent is

```
trap
```

**The difference** vs `syscall` approach is the program execution after `int3` / `trap` will continue **if and only if** debugger is attached and lldb `continue` command follows, the added value is it **won't affect the registers at all**. In the syscall approach the program will also continue execution without debugger attached with the aforementioned registers affected.

Comment: Instead of an invalid system call, you can probably use an x86 `int3` instruction (breakpoint trap) in your source code.  Or an illegal instruction, but you can probably single-step through an `int3`  without needing to manually jump to the instruction after.  ARM has a breakpoint instruction too, I forget the name.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks as always, I've added that to the answer